# Echo text depending on the variable value

Tags: php, algorithm, variables

I've created a ratio type of PHP script for the users in my platform.

Depending on how the user interact, the `$ratio` variable number changes. They start off at ratio `1.00`. The lowest they can get to is `0.00` and there is no maximum, highest user currently is on `87.50`.

I want to display a message to the user depending on what range of ratio they are at.

If their `$ratio` is anywhere between `0.00` to `0.90` then echo this:

```
<p>Your ratio is very poor!</p>
```

If between `0.91` to `1.99` then:

```
<p>Your ratio is good!</p>
```

And finally, if between `2.00` and up, then:

```
<p>You are a grandmaster!</p>
```

I am guessing that an `IF/ELSEIF` statement would be the solution to this? My platform is very trafficed so I am looking for a light-weight solution that won't put my server on health support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$ratio = 1.8;

switch ($ratio) {
    case ($ratio >= 0 && $ratio < 0.91):
        echo 'Your ratio is very poor!';
        break;
    case ($ratio >= 0.91 && $ratio < 2):
        echo 'Your ratio is good!';
        break;
    case ($ratio >= 2):
        echo 'You are a grandmaster!';
        break;
}
```

Comment: I just gave this a test run. One problem, try setting ratio to `0.00` and it does not work, it doesn't display the correct message. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: This is due to PHP string vs Integers. Try using $ratio = "0.0";

Comment: That will not work because the ratio value is never with less than two decimals, so at the very least, it will be `0.00` or for example `0.0025`...

Comment: Sorry, Any amount of decimals will work, didn't mention that.

Comment: I just tested this again with ratio `0.00` and I get the wrong message. Can you please confirm if it works for you?

Comment: $ratio = "0.00000025"; and then the same for $ratio = "0.00";

They both come back with "Your ratio is very poor!"

Comment: instead of starting at `0` you could start with`NULL`. EG: `case ($ratio >= NULL && $ratio < 0.91):`

Comment: That works great. I have one final question. How fast is this solution compared to the other answer that is posted? Micro-optimization is important for my site.

Comment: Mine: 10000 iterations: Time taken: 0.0090009999999999
The other solution 10000 iterations: Time taken: 0.117006.

I'd say mine is significantly faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use write this function:

```
function getRatioMessage($ratio) {
    if ($ratio <= 0.90) {
        $message = 'Your ratio is very poor!';
    } elseif ($ratio <= 1.99) {
        $message = 'Your ratio is good!';
    } else {
        $message = 'You are a grandmaster!';
    }

    return '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
}
```

And then use it in following way:

```
echo getRatioMessage($ratio);
```

Comment: Works great. I have however one question. How fast is this solution compared to the other one that is posted? Micro-optimization is important for my site.

Comment: `switch` seems to be faster. To be more granular, `if` statement took 0.00008s when `switch` was 0.00001s. IMHO, `if` is much readable.